# Can we add clickable info icon on tabulator column header along with the title header?

Tags: tabulator

Can we add clickable info icon on tabulator column header along with the header title?

When clicked on info icon, it should popup a div with the description of that title.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.